# adding an object into an array of objects with a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, arrayobject

I understand the commands needed to add an object to an array. I know its `array.push(object)`.

However, say I have this array of objects:

```js
const artists = [{
    "rank": 1,
    "name": "Rakim",
    "year": 1985,
    "album": "Paid in Full",
  },
  {
    "rank": 2,
    "name": "Nas",
    "year": 1994,
    "album": "Illmatic"
  }
]
```

If i needed to add a new one with a function. How would I do so? And i want to make it a function that would allow me to add more than one in the future.

So something like,

```js
function addArtist(array {}) {
  return array;
}

console.log(addArtist(array {
  new object here
}));
```

Comment: you have syntax error .. add `"album": "Paid in Full",},` in the first object

Comment: `artists.concat( newObject )`

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass an `array` of objects to the function and it to the initial one `artists` (which should be `let`) using the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let artists = [
  {
    "rank": 1,
    "name": "Rakim",
    "year": 1985,
    "album": "Paid in Full"
  },
  {
    "rank": 2,
    "name": "Nas",
    "year": 1994,
    "album": "Illmatic"
  }
]


function addArtist (artistsToAdd) {
     artists.push(...artistsToAdd);
     return artists;
}

const objects = [
  {
    "rank": 3,
    "name": "Bob",
    "year": 1995,
    "album": "Album3"
  },
  {
    "rank": 4,
    "name": "Nas",
    "year": 1992,
    "album": "Album4"
  }
];
console.log(addArtist(objects));
```

You can also use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to separate your code into multiple files and you don't want to pollute your global scope with global `artists` variable or you have multiple variables with `artists` interface, you can use:

```js
function addToArtists(artists, ...newArtists) {
  artists.push(...newArtists);
  return artists;
}
```

The script above modifies the array passed as the first parameter because arrays are reference types in JavaScript.

However, the function proposed above (without type checks) is pretty much general `addToArray` function. Therefore, from the programming style perspective I would consider to go with a more precise implementation such as:

```js
function addArtist(artists, rank, name, year, album) {
  artists.push({rank, name, year, album});
  return artists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a new artist one at a time - eg, from input by the user on the page, you could do:

```js
const artists = [{
    "rank": 1,
    "name": "Rakim",
    "year": 1985,
    "album": "Paid in Full"
  },
  {
    "rank": 2,
    "name": "Nas",
    "year": 1994,
    "album": "Illmatic"
  }
]

function addNewArtist(r, n, y, a) {
  artists.push({"rank": r, "name": n, "year": y, "album": a});
}

addNewArtist(3, "Bob", 1999, "His new one");
addNewArtist(4, "Joe", 2015, "His latest one");

console.log(artists);
```